# Post value is not working from 2nd page during data showing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want show lot's of data in multiple page where every page contains 20 data. i am searching the data after giving few value in post using form. but the post value is working for the first page during show the data. from the 2nd page the post value is not working. Below is my code of action page..

```
        <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1amShaw0n");
    mysql_select_db("bkash_plus",$conn);
    $account_no = $_POST['account_no'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
    $open_by= $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM tickets where created_by='$open_by' and status='Closed' and account_no like '%$account_no%' and remarks like '%$remarks%'");


    if(false === $result) {
       throw new Exception('Query failed with: ' . mysqli_error());
    } else {
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $row_count= $row['count'];
         }
    }

    $page_count = 0;
    if (0 === $row_count) {  
        // maybe show some error since there is nothing in your table
    } else {
       // determine page_count
       $items_per_page = 20;
       $page_count = (int)ceil($row_count / $items_per_page);
       $page = 1;
       if($page > $page_count) {
        // error to user, maybe set page to 1
        $page = 1;
       }
    }

    // make your LIMIT query here as shown above
    // determine page number from $_GET
    $page = 1;
    if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if(false === $page) {
        $page = 1;
        }
    }

    // set the number of items to display per page
    $items_per_page = 20;

    // build query
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;

     // Collects data from "friends" table 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bkash_plus.tickets where created_by='$open_by' and status='Closed' and account_no like '%$account_no%' and remarks like '%$remarks%' order by tickets_id desc LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $items_per_page) 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
    // $result = mysql_query($data) or die ("Error in query: $data. ".mysql_error()); 

    // puts the "friends" info into the $info array 
    //$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($data) >= 0) { 

    echo '<table border="2" width="1030px">
        <tr>
        <th><center><font color="blue">Ticket_ID</font><center></th>
        <th><center><font color="blue">Account No</font><center></th>
            <th><center><font color="blue">Created Time</font><center></th>
        <th><center><font color="blue">Service Type</font><center></th>
            <th><center><font color="blue">Category</font><center></th>
            <th><center><font color="blue">Sub_Category</font><center></th>
            <th><center><font color="blue">Status</font><center></th>
            <th><center><font color="blue">Remarks</font><center></th>
        <th><center><font color="blue">Created By</font><center></th>
        </tr>';

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td><center><a href=ticket_view_data_front.php?tickets_id='.$info['tickets_id'].'>'.$info['tickets_id'].'</a><center></td>
            <td><center>'.$info['account_no'].'<center></td>
                <td><center>'.$info['created_time'].'<center></td>
                <td><center>'.$info['service_type'].'<center></td>
                <td><center>'.$info['category'].'<center></td>
                <td><center>'.$info['sub_category'].'<center></td>
                <td><center>'.$info['status'].'<center></td>
                <td><center>'.$info['remarks'].'<center></td>
                <td><center>'.$info['created_by'].'<center></td>
        </tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
    }
    // later when outputting page, you can simply work with $page and $page_count to output links
    // for example
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $page_count; $i++) {
       if ($i === $page) { // this is current page
           echo 'Page ' . $i . '';
       } else { // show link to other page   
       echo '>>';
           echo '<a href="view_all_ticket_front_closed_search_result.php?page=' . $i . '">Page ' . $i . '  </a>';
       }
    }

    ?>
```

here "view_all_ticket_front_closed_search_result.php" is the action page..

For the first page i got the result of first 20 rows but during 2nd page i am getting below error...

```
Notice: Undefined index: account_no in  C:\xampp\htdocs\bkash_plus\view_all_ticket_front_closed_search_result.php on line 74

Notice: Undefined index: remarks in C:\xampp\htdocs\bkash_plus\view_all_ticket_front_closed_search_result.php on line 75
```

Below is the form page that passing the POST value..

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <!-- Account No: <input type="text" name="account_no">
                        ID: <input type="text" name="id">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check"> -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="account_no">Account ID:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account_no" name="account_no" style="height:35px;width:160px">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="remarks">Remarks:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="remarks" name="remarks" style="height:35px;width:160px">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">        
                              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 ticket">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="View" formaction="view_all_ticket_front_closed_search_result.php">
                              </div>
                        </div>
                       </form>
```

Anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: How are passing  $_POST['account_no'];?

Comment: two values are passing from submit page..one is $_POST['account_no'] and another is $_POST['remarks']

Comment: Where is your submit page?

Comment: submit page has been added in the main question now...

Comment: But the form is not submitted everytime right, only for the first time you submit account number etc and use pagination.

Comment: can you please let me know the solution or how can i pass the value in every page..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Once you the form next time on the click of pagination link you have to pas it as a query string and get the value of the account number using $_GET